# PHP connection issue in mac

Tags: php, macos, mamp

i'm using **MAMP** on mac os 
This is the error while making database connection

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/databases.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/databases.php on line 3

Code used

```
<?php 

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$connection)
{

    die("Database connection failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Fortunately you are using a version of PHP that this bad function is deprecated and removed. Time to learn new things.

Comment: So where can i find that new information.. I'm a newbie it might help if you could provide certain resources @RoyalBg. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you are : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Thanks @RoyalBg That really helped me.

Comment: check Output of phpinfo()

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to use `PHP 7`, then it is time to learn something new, as `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since a while, and are now removed from `PHP 7` as [seen in this RFC.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7)

If you are unsure about which version you are using, you can call [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/phpinfo) and this will show your current PHP version.

Alternatives:

- [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 5):

just change 
from

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

to

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

notice the 'i' in mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php  

   $database = mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
   mysql_select_db("databasename",$database);

?>
```

Comment: no need to use password, he is using php 7, mysql_query is not available in php 7

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.